# Convert return new array in Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to convert a return new array in Java to Kotlin. I have tried using the docs but doesn't seem to work.

Below is the java code

```
public ScoreController[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ScoreController[size];
    }
```

Below is Kotlin code that I trying to do

```
override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GenderController> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
```

The kotlin code isn't happy :(

Answer (score 3):

You're explicitly returning an `Array` that contains `null` values, you have to adjust your return type to allow for that:

```
override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GenderController?> {
    return arrayOfNulls(size)
}
```

This can be seen from the signature of the [`arrayOfNulls`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) function, it returns an `Array<T?>`:

```
fun <reified T> arrayOfNulls(size: Int): Array<T?>
```